# How do I share a printer from behind a router in Windows?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, router, printer, sharing

I have a computer running Windows 7 with a printer attached to it that I want to share with the rest of the network. Preferably, I would like to have this work as simply as possible and with minimal change of the network. My network is set up like so:

```
      [ISP]
        |
   [Main router]
        |
   -----------
   |         |
 [C1]  [Other Router]
             |-----------------|
          [C2 & Printer]      [C3]
```

In the diagram above, the printer is connected to C2 via USB, and C2 is running Windows 7 Professional x64. C1 is running Windows 10 x64, and C3 is running Windows 98 Second Edition. C1 and the other router are connected to the main router via WiFi extenders, which seem to be transparent, i.e. they do not behave as routers. Knowing that this probably will not work with C3, I don't necessarily *need* Windows 98 to have the printer, but it would be nice if I could get that to work. My question is, how do I get at least the printer on C2 visible to C1? I have file and printer sharing enabled but it seems as though the router is "blocking" access to the rest of the LAN (C1).

For reference:
"other router" is a Netgear WGR614v10
WiFi extenders are Netgear WN3000RPv2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume the routers connect the various parts of the network. Test it by making sure the PCs can "ping" each other. If they can, do the followin,

On C2, make sure the printer is shared, and permissions are set so that C1 has read/write access. Make a note of the printer's sharename. Click the "Additional Drivers" button and install the Win7 drivers. You should be able to get them from the manufacturer's website.

Now go to C1 and install to the printer. You can do that from Devices & Printers, as s "network printer", or by typing "\C2_name\printer_sharename" at the Start menu.

The same should be possible from C3, but your problem will be to get Win98 drivers for a modern printer. Check the manufacturer's website to see if you can find them.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to connect the printer directly to your router (or switch) via an RJ45-Port and an straight-trough ethernet cable (standard wired connection). If this is not possible in your case, you can try 1 of these methods:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-easiest-ways-share-printer-network/

Good luck